# Issues with WebIDE CRUD template and OData errors

Tags: sapui5

Has anyone successfully based an application off the WebIDE Fiori CRUD template? It doesn't seem to be able to handle errors in the batch OData request properly.

For example when you select an item in the master list and click EDIT to update it and I enter a value that I know will cause an error in the backend. The batch OData request is sent and the response is successful (overall) even though internally the update failed. You see a bad request 400 error in the console but the app doesn't react to it.

Using the ErrorHandler.js object you can easily code a message box to show a nice error message, however the app seems to get confused and always navigates to the top item in the list but the ODataModel still has pending changes so if you try to navigate it shows the data loss dialog.

Trying to debug it is very painful given the nature of the code with Promises inside promises inside promises and callbacks firing everywhere!!

Maybe there is a better example CRUD application to base your apps on?

Answer (score 1):

Well.... Some more debugging and I've found that all of the weird issues occurring with the Fiori CRUD template are due to the model defaulting to auto refreshing after changes. 
Which typically is a nice feature as the user does not have to hit the refresh button to see changes that have been made after adding a new entry or editing an object.

But this auto refresh on the model seems to play havoc with updates in batch mode. 
Firstly, if the batch update is completely successful the app navigates to the first item in the master list - which is should not.
Secondly, when there is an error in the batch of sorts of weird shit happens.

So to fix this I just call oModel.setRefreshAfterChange(false) before the oModel.submitChanges() call (only when updating, not creating). The in the callback after the save is completed we reset auto refresh to true.

The crud app now works as expected and can correctly handle errors in the odata batch update without strange ui updates.

Answer (score 0):

Jason,

but the error message they are providing is very simple, and does not support parsing error body like :

```
<code>005056A509B11ED199D882461C8C40FE</code><message xml:lang="en">The Data Services Request version '3.0' is not supported for the request payload.</message><
```

we have to do the code for parsing the errors then show in the message box